# Spring+quartz should I make my own bean?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I need a job that can run every 1 minutes betwen 17h and 18h, it should not be relaunched if the job is unfinished.

The org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean seems to be what I need but I found nothing about concurrency.

Would you know a quartz bean which would fit my needs?
Every javadoc I found has almost all its link broken.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/CronTriggerBean.html

Or will I have to make my own kind of bean?

quartz is in 1.8.5 and spring in 2.5.6
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Sure, the CronTriggerBean is suitable for your case. The expression you need is 0 * 17 * * ? and will run for every minute starting at 17.00 with the last trigger happening at 17.59.

-In order to disable concurrency, in newer versions you can put @DisallowConcurrentExecution over your job class. In 1.8 version I think that annotation is not supported, and instead you need to put "implements StatefulJob" in your job class so that it implements StatefulJob that can be run only by one thread a time

-a sample app using quartz 1.8 can be found at http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

Answer (score 0):

The 2.5 JavaDoc can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/index.html).

In Spring 2.5 you can set a concurrent attribute in the XML when using MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean. Setting it prevents multiple instances from running at the same time, but it should be noted that triggers will be queued up and launched when the previous instance of the job finishes.

Here is a sample:

```
    <bean id="fooJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="fooManager" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="myJOb" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="true"/>    
    </bean>
```